# How to test delivery in PublishSubscribeChannel?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I have a `PublishSubscribeChannel` in my application, which should deliver messages to different `MessageHandlers` inside the same JVM. Handlers are subscribed to the channel using `@StreamListener` annotation. Channel uses `Executors` so delivery is asynchronous.

Now, I want to test that senders and handlers agree on the specific object type which send through channel (the type of `Message` body). AFAIU I have two ways to test this:

1. Find all subscribers of the given channel and verify their
   signature.
2. Send a message to a channel and verify that no handlers have thrown an exception.

I have no idea how to do (1). And I think I could do (2) by listening to `errorChannel` (there should be no messages there), but I don't quite understand how long should I wait for error messages.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

For 1, you can use reflection to look at the collection of handlers in the channel's dispatcher; then use reflection again to look at the hander's `Method`.

However, your design is flawed, unless you don't mind losing messages; the incoming message will be ack'd as soon as you hand off to the executor; if the server then crashes, the message will be lost.

If you get rid of the executor, it would be simpler to add an interceptor to the channel, which will be notified of any exceptions in its `afterSendCompletion()` method (satisfying your 2).

Comment: Re design flaw. Yes, I have this concern, but as my handlers perform IO and thus can block, I want to process incoming messages concurrently. Using executor is the only method I know for this.

Comment: You should increase the consumer `concurrency` instead of adding an executor.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, how increasing concurrency without an executor can help if my channel is within one JVM. Can you point me to some doc?

Comment: The `@StreamListener` is backed by a listener container which manages the threads via the `concurrency` property - it uses a task executor internally. See [concurrency](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.SR1/reference/htmlsingle/#_consumer_properties). Handing off to your own executor will cause message loss in the event of a failure.

Comment: You shouldn't use a pub/sub channel at all; the binder will call multiple `@StreamListeners` in sequence and only ack the message if the last one is successful. If you want them to be called concurrently, you should bind a new channel for each, with each having a different consumer `group`.